# I sinned what should I do?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, sin, human-rights

I am a Muslim female. In the past I was very insecure and used photos of other girls and I claimed that those were photos of me when I sent it to other guys I was talking to online when they would ask, cause they are really pretty! I never spoke to any of the girls (one knew who I was however we never spoke but the others don't know me at all). Now that Allah has called me back to Him I am really religious and trying to be the best Muslim I can. I now realise and really regret my mistake however I am fearful Allah will throw me into jahannam because of the “rights of others” concept where that person must forgive you first.

Have I breached their rights according to Islam? I never made the girls look bad and the guys I spoke to don't know them either.

I have repented to Allah many times and deeply, deeply regret my past actions and have cried thinking about it because I'm so worried what will happen to me on judgment day.

Please help me, do I need to confront and confess to those girls and ask for their forgiveness even though their photos were complimented? That would be extremely embarrassing and hard since I don't know them and would make my life miserable and they would hate me and tell everyone they know! I wouldn't be able to bear that because i would be so ashamed!

Ahstaghfirulla

Comment: What I know so far, You must ask forgiveness from those girls if you want to be ensured that abused rights were amended.
But who knows, Allah is the most merciful. His mercy reigns over his rage.
Allah might acknowledge your repentance and take the abused rights of others on himself to be compensated in other ways that we might never know but what I just said is speculation based on the the name Ar-Raheem.
But islamic law says that you must ask forgiveness if you want to be cleared and that shame you said at last portion might be the punishment for covering your sins in the this life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m sorry to hear this, but that’s a sign that you’re a believer. Usually believers do feel fear when they do mistakes. And God knows that you feel regret and the doors of repentance are open, and He’s ready To forgive any sin that you committed.

Secondly, you can be far more intelligent and smarter than these guys and just, you know, try to manipulate their minds( guys’s minds) and make them as if they saw a picture from someone else and not from you.

First of, why were you insecure? Girls should be taught, bad assess, that’s how they get whatever they want from others. What social network do they have? If you sent them through **WhatsApp**, you can delete them completely, and when they try to show to other girls about this picture, they couldn’t see it.

In Facebook, I think it’s the same with WhatsApp.

I guess you still have chance to delete the pictures you sent, and then when these girls ask about your pictures tell them that you never claimed that these pictures wasn’t you. And you can also **delete** the messages completely so that you can hide the truth from them and keep it **secret** and if they ask you about this just because these boys showed them, you tell them, “why do you even believe in them? They have no prove at all” but you must also, keep your device home and pretend as if haven’t done any picture as an excuse, and then attend **NEVER** to repeat this mistake again, and turn to God in repentance, because He Said:

> ”O Believers! Turn to your Lord (God) in repentance that you might succeed”

This verse is actually from Quran! I To be honest, I didn’t invented this one.

And remember always, God is All-Watching, All-Aware. Absolutely no one can hide from Him.

And after this, forget completely as if never happened.

I hope my advice is good.

Answer (score 1):

As‘salaamu alaikum, little sister.

With regard to the sin of lying, ask Allah for forgiveness and mend your conduct. That is, stop the practice of lying, period.

As a young woman of Faith, you should also leave off from communicating freely with laa mahram young men.

With regard to the young women whose faces you used, it is not clear to me from what you said that you did an actual wrong against them. Did you do or say anything that may cause them harm or loss? For example, did you talk dirty to any of the young men you communicated with? If so then you might have inadvertantly ruined those young ladies‘s reputation by making some young man think that the girls are wild and  loose young women. That‘s not cool, and you shouldn‘t leave that situation where it‘s at. You have to find a way to make it right.

I don‘t think you have to go and confess to those girls. You DO need to go tell those young men that the pics that they had been seeing were not you.

I leave you with this passage from the Qur‘an....

“O My servants who have transgressed against their own souls! Do not despair of the Mercy of Allah. TRULY, ALLAH FORGIVES ALL SINS. Indeed, He is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful.

“Turn back to your Lord and submit to Him, before the Punishment comes upon you. After that, you will not be helped.” Qur‘an 39:53-54

May Allah  have mercy upon us all, and forebear with our short-comings.

Ma‘as‘salaam.

Comment: I dont talk to the men anymore. What should i do? With one of the girls photo i did talk dirty with a guy but i deleted our coversations and cant find him anywhere because it was through an online social platform. If i were to confess to the girl will i need to show her what i look like or tell her my name? Or can i message her anonymously and ask for her forgiveness?

Comment: I think an  anonymous message will suffice, provided you give the young lady enough info about the situation to allow her to be able to understand and appreciate how you wronged her. Withold your identity but give her all the facts. THEN make your sincere apology and ask her if  she can find it in her heart to forgive you. If she forgives you‘re in the clear. If not fast for a few days and give some sadaqah (if you can afford it) as expiation for the sin. May Allah accept it from, and send you a good muslim man to love and make you feel like the queen you are. Ameen. Ma‘as‘salaam.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Its terrible being a teenager in this generation since there is so much technology and social standards present that i forgot my own religion and fallen victim to it and now i have to pay for my mistakes..insAllah she will forgive me

Comment: It‘s good and healthy to feel ashamed after having done wrong, but you don‘t have to beat yourself up over it. In this Deen, the key is to make tawbah (repentence), which you have already done, and to then do better going forward. “When those who believe come to you say, ‘Peace be upon you. Your Lord has ordained the rule of Mercy for Himself. If any of you did evil in ignorance, AND THEN REPENTED AND MADE AMENDS - behold! He is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful.“ Qur‘an 6:54. Alhamdulillahi Rab‘bil ‘Aalameen!

Comment: I understand but judgement day is a scary thing. If she doesnt forgive do i give sadaqah to her or the poor and needy? Sorry for all the questions im just trying to fix this!

Comment: The poor and needy, definitely.

Comment: Alhamdullillah thank you so much for you advice Ibraheem may Allah have mercy on your soul